# axios successful request but data is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm uploading multiple files separately using axios.

This is the request(all the following code is inside an async function):

```js
const proms = files.map(file => {
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", file);
  return axios.post(`/upload/${userId}`, formData)
});
```

proms will be an array of promises so I proceed to Promise.all it:

```js
const res = await Promise.all(proms)
```

If I do `console.log(res)` it shows a successfull response from server as you can see here:

```js
Array(3) [ {…}, {…}, {…} ]​
  0: Object { data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", … }​​
    config: Object { timeout: 0, xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN", xsrfHeaderName: "X-XSRF-TOKEN", … }​​
    data: Object { fieldname: "file", originalname: "612_photo.jpg", encoding: "7bit", … }​​​
    destination: ********************​​****
    encoding: "7bit"​​​
    fieldname: "file"​​​
    filename: "/1648309550808-586868206.jpeg"​​​
    mimetype: "image/jpeg"​​​
    originalname: "612_photo.jpg"​​​
    path: ********************​​****
    size: 43267​​​
    <prototype>: Object { … }​​
    headers: Object { "content-length": "395", "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" }​​
    request: XMLHttpRequest { readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, … }​​
    status: 200​​
    statusText: "OK"​​
    <prototype>: Object { … }​
  1: Object { data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", … }​
  2: Object { data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", … }​
  length: 3​
  <prototype>: Array []
```

But then when I do `console.log(res.data)` it is undefined. What is happening here?

Comment: `res` is an Array of objects right? If you attempt to do `res.data` it will be undefined. If you acces for example the first object, `res[0].data` do you get undefined?

Comment: @ask4you, wow almost 3 hours wrapping around my head on this and I didn't noticed that, thanks!

Comment: If you want to access whole data you can use loop there !!

Answer (score 0):

your response(res) is An array so you cant access res.data ,try :

```
res.forEach(item=>{console.log(item.data)})
```